# Adding anchor tag with insertafter in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm a newbie to jquery. I want to know why can't I insert an anchor tag with insertafter, but I can add h2 tag and other tags. Please help me. and here is the link to the code.

http://jsbin.com/iboquj/4/edit

```
    $(function(){

         $('<h2>',{
            text:'Hello from javascript',
            class:'myClass'

         }).insertAfter('article'); 

      $('<a></a>',{

        href:'http://google.com',

      }).insertAfter('article');

    });
```

Comment: In the `<h2>` example you only have an opening tag, while in the `<a>` example you close the tag. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Hi, it works both the same, and I found the answer by kundan, that I was missing to give anchor text. thanks for fast help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you didn't define the body of anchor tag that's why its not showing.

Try this instead :

```
$('<a></a>',{
    href:'http://google.com',
    text: 'Google'
}).insertAfter('article');
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/iboquj/6/edit)**

This will fix your issue.

Comment: Make sure to inspect the DOM next time. The anchor was indeed there, but just didn't render anything on the page.